# FFMPEG - Encode audio in a planar format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to convert a stereo audio file in pcm_s32le_planar format. I don't care about the container (AIFF/FLAC/MP3), just the memory layout.

`ffmpeg.exe -formats` says :

```
 DE s32le           PCM signed 32-bit little-endian
```

`ffmpeg.exe -codecs` says :

```
DEA..S pcm_s32le_planar     PCM signed 32-bit little-endian planar
```

`.\ffmpeg.exe -encoders`says :

```
A..... pcm_s32le_planar     PCM signed 32-bit little-endian planar
```

So really it should be possible.

However :

`.\ffmpeg.exe -i in.flac -acodec pcm_s32le_planar out.aiff` says :

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

`.\ffmpeg.exe -i in.flac -f s32le -acodec pcm_s32le_planar out.aiff` outputs a file, but it's not an AIFF file : it seems that using `-f` forces RAW output (so, no header of any kind, just the audio data)

How can I have planar, signed 32-bit, litte-endian audio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg only writes planar PCM to NUT format, so

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.flac -acodec pcm_s32le_planar out.nut
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there some place I could have found this (on top of the source code) ?

Comment: Sorry, there's no global list or one-stop resource.